# Redirecting with react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following route config:

```
const route = {
    path: 'services',

    getComponent(nextState, callback) {
        require.ensure([], (require) => {
            callback(null, require('./components/services').default)
        })
    },
    //getIndexRoute(partialNextState, callback) {
    //    require.ensure([], (require) => {
    //        callback(null, {component: require('./components/consulting').default})
    //    })
    //},
    childRoutes: [
        {
            path: 'consulting',
            getComponent(nextState, callback) {
                require.ensure([], (require) => {
                    callback(null, require('./components/consulting').default)
                })
            }
        }
    ],
    indexRedirect: {
        //from: 'services',
        to: 'consulting'
    }
}

export default route
```

But when I go to `/services` I receive the error:

> TypeError: element is null

When I used the `getIndexRoute` it worked fine, but now I wish to rather redirect to `/services/consulting`. What is this error, considering I know it is not the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IndexRedirect` isn't available in object notation, just as a *jsx* component. If you would like to reproduce it's behaviour you should use `onEnter` hook for redirection. More details are described [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/IndexRoutes.md#index-redirects).

So, you should change:

```
indexRedirect: {
    //from: 'services',
    to: 'consulting'
}
```

to:

```
indexRoute: { 
    onEnter: (nextState, replace) => replace('/consulting') 
}
```